# How the present technology influences the way history of science is done?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, computer-science

Heard recently about digital humanities as a new paradigm of inquiry into the history of mankind and other humanities. Is the historiography of science informed by technological advances that could enable a perhaps greater number of resources to analyze for us to learn about the past? Is there ongoing research about it? Do historians of science say something about current technological capabilities in the context of the historiography of the sciences?

Answer (score 4):

It helped lead to the discovery of the wrong widely used image for the mathematician Legendre. See https://www.ams.org/notices/200911/rtx091101440p.pdf.